# How do I define an entire object and methods on single line

Tags: groovy

This throws an error (can't set on null object)

```
def currentBuild = [:].rawBuild.getCauses = { return 'hudson.model.Cause$UserIdCause@123abc' }
```

I need to do it on multiple lines like this

```
def currentBuild = [:]
currentBuild.rawBuild = [:]
currentBuild.rawBuild.getCauses = { return 'hudson.model.Cause$UserIdCause@123abc' }
```

Is there a terse way to define this object on a single line or statement? I don't understand why my single line attempt doesn't work.

Comment: A quick reminder rd888 that your spelling needs correction with nearly every post. Could I trouble you to start using a spell checker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of chaining setters, I'd just use a map literal with the nested
values.  E.g.

```
def currentBuild = [rawBuild: [getCauses: { return 'hudson.model.Cause$UserIdCause@123abc' }]]

println currentBuild.rawBuild.getCauses()
// → hudson.model.Cause$UserIdCause@123abc
```

If you have to go more imperative instead of declarative, have a look at
`.get(key, fallback)`, `.withDefault{ ... }`, `.tap{ ... }`.

BTW: those are *not* objects but just maps.

Comment: "BTW: those are not objects but just maps." - maps are objects.